# URL for querying Facebook by Facebook Query Language (FQL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What is the proper way to query Facebook by Facebook Query Language (FQL)?

The documentation for 'Stream':
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/
says query "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT" in the example ("Try this query")
Note: To query the stream, it is perfectly possible to use the "graph.facebook.com".

However, the others, for example, the 'Comment':
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/
says query "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select" in the example ("Try this query")

So, which is which? Which is better for performance? Because both works, will Facebook obsolete one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second URL is the Graph API url, which is the current preferred method: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=QUERY`.

The other url `api.facebook.com` is the REST API url. According to the [REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) page:

> We are in the process of deprecating the REST API. If you are building a new Facebook app, please use the Graph API. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, the Graph API is the center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new features will be found.

So in this case, performance isn't the issue. Use the `graph` url.